# NameError: Name 'pets' is not defined. PYTHON

Tags: python, nameerror

This is the code I am using, but every time I try to run it, I get this error in Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex11.py", line 16, in <module>
    if pets == "y":
NameError: name 'pets' is not defined
```

My code:

```
print "So, how are you doing today?"
emotion = raw_input()

if "Good" in emotion:
    print "Cool! I love when people are \"good\"! It makes me feel all fuzzy inside. ^-^"
    print "Do you have any pets? y/n."
    pets = raw_input()

if pets == "y":
    print "Awesome! I have always wanted a pet! What kind do you have? What does it look like?"
    pet_type = raw_input()
```

Comment: Hint: what happens when `"Good" in emotion` returns `False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that if `"Good"` is not in `emotion`, `pets` does not get defined. Thus, define it first:

```
print "So, how are you doing today?"
emotion = raw_input()
pets = "n" #here

if "Good" in emotion:
    print "Cool! I love when people are \"good\"! It makes me feel all fuzzy inside. ^-^"
    print "Do you have any pets? y/n."
    pets = raw_input()

if pets == "y":
    print "Awesome! I have always wanted a pet! What kind do you have? What does it look like?"
    pet_type = raw_input()
```